# emailed pdf extraction and processing

Tags: pdf, extract, power-automate

My company receives a large number of invoices via mail. The most common is that the email contains a link to download a PDF. The PDF is then stored in a folder where it then dissected by a human to extract information which is then compared to the contract.

What would you recommend for a 3rd party product that will download the PDF, give it a unique name and the extract the required information to CSV. Once in a CSV format I can then manipulate it to do the contract validation.

My programming skills are confined to the Unix Shell, a tiny bit of C and an even smaller amount of VBA

Thanks

I briefly looked at Power Automate as a possible solution. It looks like it could do what I want but I'm no sure what the cost would be for the volume of invoices, between 500-600, twice a month.